# Multiple role based registration in mvc4 c# aspx

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 5 roles of users.They are Admin,Distributor,Micro-distributor,Dealer and User.Admin has the privilege of accessing  all pages of other user and all CRUD operations on it.All these users have different fields from others.If dealer register his details then the values stored into a register table in SQL server database.this is same for all roles.basic details of all users columns are same.but other details like bank details and shop details are extra columns of distributors and dealers.So you can store the registration details to one column or different columns.but user can login to their account based on their roles,that is if a dealer tries to login,then server must check such a dealer exist in the database.If yes then he redirect to his profile page.I need the complete model view and controller source code for this problem in mvc4 or mvc3.you canuse the sql server database for this action...

I use the following code snippet for login action

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(UserLogon u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (TranzEntities2 dc = new TranzEntities2())
            {
                var v = dc.tbl_User.Where(a => a.user_name.Equals(u.user_name) && a.password.Equals(u.password)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (v != null)
                {
                    Session["LogedUserID"] = v.user_id.ToString();
                    Session["LogedUserFullname"] = v.first_name.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Login failed, Try again");
                }

            }
        }
        return View(u);
    }
```

But it is for only one table.I need to check the user login based on their roles.Suppose if someone try to login then it automatically check the user belongs to which table.if he belongs to a dealer table then dealer page will redirect after login success.

Comment: Are you tried yet? Add your code snippet also.

Comment: I doubt anyone will solve the whole issue for you. Try to implement it and put the code snippet if there are any issues.